# ERROR - Request returns 429 error! Instagrambot

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

> import os import time import random import logging from instabot
> import Bot import requests
>
> ## Configure logging logging.basicConfig(filename='app.log', filemode='w', format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
>
> level=logging.WARNING)
>
> ## Login to Instagram with session management def login_with_retry(bot, username, password, retry_count=3, delay_base=5):
>
> ```
> for _ in range(retry_count):
>     try:
>         bot.login(username=username, password=password, use_cookie=True)
>         print("Login successful!")
>         return True
>     except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
>         if err.response.status_code == 429:
>             print("Requests Exception found.")
>             logging.warning(err)
>             raise err
>         else:
>             print(f"Error logging in: {err}")
>             # If login fails, retry after a delay
>             print("Retrying after a delay...")
>             time.sleep(delay_base * (_ + 1) + random.uniform(1, 3))  # Add randomized delay
>     except Exception as e:
>         print(f"Error logging in: {e}")
>         # If login fails, retry after a delay
>         print("Retrying after a delay...")
>         time.sleep(delay_base * (_ + 1) + random.uniform(1, 3))  # Add randomized delay
> return False
> ```
>
> def main():
> # Create an instance of Bot
> bot = Bot()
>
> ```
> # Your Instagram credentials
> username = ""
> password = ""
>
> # Login with retry
> if login_with_retry(bot, username, password):
>     try:
>         # Follow a user 
>         try:
>             bot.follow(["@spotify", "@applemusic"])
>             time.sleep(random.uniform(120, 180))  # Randomize sleep time between 120 to 180 seconds
>         except Exception as e:
>             print(f"Error following users: {e}")
>             print("Waiting for 60 seconds before retrying...")
>             time.sleep(60)  # Sleep for 60 seconds before retrying
>
>         try:
>             bot.unfollow(["@spotify", "@applemusic"])
>             time.sleep(random.uniform(120, 180))  # Randomize sleep time between 120 to 180 seconds
>         except Exception as e:
>             print(f"Error unfollowing users: {e}")
>             print("Waiting for 60 seconds before retrying...")
>             time.sleep(60)  # Sleep for 60 seconds before retrying
>     finally:
>         bot.logout()  # Ensure logout even if an exception occurs
> else:
>     print("Failed to login after multiple attempts. Please check your Instagram credentials.")
> ```
>
> if **name** == "**main**":
> main()

i. **Setting Up Logging**: I configured the logging to track warnings and above. The log messages are being written to 'app.log' in write mode.

ii. **Logging into Instagram**: I created a function `login_with_retry` that tries to log into Instagram with a given username and password. This function attempts to log in up to `retry_count` times, with an increasing delay between each attempt. If the login fails due to a `requests.exceptions.HTTPError` with a status code of 429, the error is logged and re-raised. For other exceptions, the error is printed and the function retries after a delay.

iii. **Following and Unfollowing Users**: If the login is successful, the script tries to follow and then unfollow the users "@spotify" and "@applemusic". If an exception occurs during these operations, the error is printed, the script waits for 60 seconds, and then retries.

iv. **Logging Out**: Regardless of whether an exception occurs, the script ensures that the bot logs out of Instagram.

Comment: 429 is "too many requests".  How fast are you trying to get data?

Comment: @stdunbar i'm trying to get data between 3-5 minutes